# Jenkins - FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: jenkins

I just started using Jenkins and I'm seeing an issue where my slave services is crashing while running a job(the job executes an .exe program).  The error I'm seeing is as follows -

```
FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:41)
    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:174)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:714)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:167)
    at $Proxy46.join(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:925)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:360)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:94)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:63)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:781)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:562)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:299)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:774)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:69)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:77)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2248)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2541)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2551)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
    at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
```

Any help or insight on why this is happening would be great!

Eric

Comment: Did you loose your network connection?

Comment: no - I checked that I can get to the slave when the issue happened.

Comment: check all logfiles. Server logs, slave logs, build logs, ....

Comment: could be this problem: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13253

Answer (score 6):

I am using Jenkins. Go the particular *node*, 
Click on *Configuration* then in JVM options enter  **-Xms512m -Xmx1024m**

That will increase the heap size.

Comment: I had a similar problem and increased the memory when I started the slave jar. ` java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar slave.jar.`